# jquery-1.11.2.min.js to jquery-3.5.1.min.js : Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

recently i changed my cshtml page refers been replaced from jquery-1.11.2.min.js TO https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js

after that the below code returns error as "Unhandled exception at line 2, column 84827 in https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'
"

May i know how to resolve this error

```js
var app = angular.module('publicHomeApp', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('PublicHomeController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
    //alert('index page load');

    var post = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/PublicHome/GetPublicHomeContent",
        dataType: 'json',
        //data: { strInput: $scope.lblUserNameContent },
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    });

    post.success(function (data, status) {
        //alert('success');

        $scope.lblFeedback1Content = data.Feedback1;
        $scope.lblFeedback2Content = data.Feedback2;
        $scope.lblFeedback3Content = data.Feedback3;
        $scope.lblCloseContent = data.Close;

        //$scope.loading = false;
    });

    post.error(function (data, status) {
        $window.alert(data.Message);
        //$scope.ShowSpinnerStatus = false;

        //$scope.loading = false;
    });

});
```

Comment: experts could you please help me to resolve this exception